# Existing listing no longer editable after introduction of new Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

This is a question for google apps marketplace support people. After the introduction of the new Google Apps Marketplace, I am no longer able to edit exising listing from my Vendor Profile in the Google Apps Marketplace. I get the following error whenever I try to edit an exisitng listing:

"Error
Sorry, something just went wrong. To get back to the front page follow this link."

I would have thought that existing listings would still be editable from my vendor profile. Is this not the case?

Regards,
LT

Comment: Hi, I have reported this to Google, and they're looking into this.

Comment: Yes are aware of this at Google and are looking into it.

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: Google has fixed the issue (a while ago). I am able to edit existing old app market listings.