# I can not save my marketplace listing on Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I can not save my marketplace listing since last Friday. It happens on any existing listing of mine.

1. On Google Apps Marketplace top page, click "My Vendor Profile"
2. Click "Edit" button from listings
3. You will see edit mode of listing, just click "Save and Preview"
4. Error happens.

Does anybody face same problem?
What is happening on Google Apps Marketplace?

Thank you,

Akitoshi Abe

Comment: seems like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276554/existing-listing-no-longer-editable-after-introduction-of-new-google-apps-market. Please follow that.